# How to automatically add/drop table on an existing replication?

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I have a database in `SQL Server 2008 R2` (e.g. `Publisher`). I made a replication of its tables and data to a subscriber (e.g. `Subscriber`).

Then I add a tables (e.g. `AddedTable`), and drop another tables (e.g. `DropedTable`) at the publisher.

How can I reload all the "*existing*" tables to the subscriber automatically? Is there way to do this in `SQL Server 2008 r2`?

Kind regards
Amin

Comment: No. Mirroring is not an appropriate option in my case. I don't want to use the subscriber as a backup-only.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an a new article involves adding the article to the publication, creating a new snapshot, and synchronizing the subscription to apply the schema and data for the newly added article.  Reinitialization is not required, but a new snapshot is.

Dropping an article from a publication involves dropping the articles, creating a new snapshot, and synchronizing subscriptions.  Special considerations must be made for Merge publications with parameterized filters and compatibility level lower than 90RTM.

This is covered in [Add Articles to and Drop Articles from Existing Publications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152493.aspx).

Comment: So what I understand from your answer is that, what i am looking for is not possible?

Comment: It is absolutely possible, you must follow the instructions in the link I provided.